# String attribute in Razor as a part of onclick confirmation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, onclick, url.action

I need a confirm window before calling the action specified in `Url.Action`. My code is:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "OriginalWorks", new {id = w.Id})" 
onclick="return confirm('Do you... '+ @w.Title + '?')"><span></span></a>
```

Where `w` is the instance of the OriginalWork class. If I look into HTML of the site, there is the right string value in confirm, but the window doesn't show and the action is called immediately. If a do the same with an int attribute, for example `Id`:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "OriginalWorks", new {id = w.Id})" 
onclick="return confirm('Do you... '+ @w.Id + '?')"><span></span></a>
```

It works as expected, showing a message in an confirm window with an value of Id.

I tried `Title.toString()`, but it doesn't help. I think it would work with `Html.ActionLink`, but I want to use this because of `span` in a `a` element.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: May be the w.Title is null ?

Comment: Can you confirm what is " the right string value in confirm"? Are there any quotes in the string breaking the javascript?

Comment: Yep. Most likely you've got a stray single quote in your string value, which is causing the JS string to be terminated prematurely and causing a JS error.

Comment: There were no quotes in the string, I just joined the strings badly, see my answer. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. Solved it now, I didn't realize that the w.Title value was evaluated as a variable (and JavaScript maybe tried to find a variable called like a Title value), not as a string value. It simply works like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "OriginalWorks", new {id = w.Id})" 
onclick="return confirm('Do you... @w.Title?')"><span></span></a>
```

So there is an expected string value of Title.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode for your w.Title to awoid escape chars that can break javascript

Comment: The problem wasn't in this, but good recommendation, will use.